# What is the difference between CAMO and CAME?

Tags: easa-regulations

Could someone explain the difference between a Continuing Airworthiness Management Exposition CAME and a Continuing Airworthiness Management Organization CAMO?

Comment: I think this explains: http://www.bazl.admin.ch/experten/luftfahrzeuge/03277/index.html?lang=en. CAMO are organisations. CAME is a document (or filing?).

Comment: [Airworthiness Management Camo](http://fr.slideshare.net/spsinghame/airworthiness-management-camo)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CAMO is the organisation and CAME is a "book" that need to write.

This "book" contain procedure to explain how you will work (how you communicate with aircraft customers, how you manage your docs, etc...).